# ActiveRecord - find_by v/s where

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the difference between rails constructs:

```
authentication = Authentication.where(:provider=>omniauth['provider'], :uid=>omniauth['uid'])
authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
```

My problems is that if I use first construct (.where) - I am unable to get the association. My model Authentication 'belongs to' model user. If I search for the Authentication using first construct, I am not able to get associated User via : authentication.user, but the same thing works with the second version.

I want to use the first construct instead of the second one because of Heroku issue :
http://docs.heroku.com/database : PGError: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer.

Comment: I'm using heroku too and the second one works just fine. Are both your provider and uid in string type?

Comment: uid is varchar but when its compared by numbers, I get the error from Postgres.  I am using omniauth authentication method. Not sure how to fix this

Comment: maybe call .to_s on omniauth['uid'], so rails think it's string and pass it to postgres as varchar?

Comment: i posted comment as another answer. mark it as ok so others can know this is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PGError: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer.

It's not heroku issue. Postgresql since 8.4 or 8.3 introduced more restrictive type checking. For example if your column "position" is integer you can't write this sql:

```
select * from orders where position = '1';
```

It will return error similar to yours.

You could try:

```
auth = Authentication.find :all, :conditions => ["provider = ? and uid = ?", provider, uid]
```

Comment: This fails too. When I do auth.user.email, I get : NoMethodError (undefined method `user' for #<Array:0xabc3acc>), I think the returned value is an array and not Authentication Object.

Answer (score 1):

Repost good answer from comments:

maybe call .to_s on omniauth['uid'], so rails think it's string and pass it to postgres as varchar?